# Redirect after option has been chosen

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I have this script, that gives me possiblity of menu for user.

How to make user being redirect to specific page after specific choice has been made?

```
<form action="...">
    <select name="name">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Option 1 = option1.php
Option 2 = option2.php

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562095/redirect-on-select-option-in-select-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to redirect on select of option itself, or on submit of form, In former case, you need it in jquery (client side) and in the latter, you can do it in server side on form submit.

For Client Side:

```
jQuery("#select_id").on('change', function(){
   var urlPath = jQuery(this).val().data('url');
   window.location.href = "http://www.projecturl.com/"+urlPath;
});
```

given the select id looks as below,

```
<select id="select_id">
   <option data-url="option1.php">Option 1</option>
   <option data-url="option2.php">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

For Server Side:

You need to write the redirection logic in the form submission action depending on param you receive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onchange` event of the `select`:

**Step 1:**

```
<script>
  function redirectChange() {
      var newUrl = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
      document.location.href = "http://www.yourbaseurl.com/" + newUrl;
  }

</script>
```

**Step 2 - Option 1:**
After the function hook up the event using `addEventListener` (I prefer this way as it allows chaining - notice you must add an html `id` to the `select`)

```
<script>
document.getElementById("<insert your select id").addEventListener("change",redirectChange,false);  
</script>
```

**Step2 - Option 2:**
Or change the html with direct `onchange` event hooking (I prefer the previous)

```
<form action="...">
    <select name="name" onchange="redirectChange(this)>
        <option value="option1.php">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2.php">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mapVz/1/

Comment: Works as honey. Thank you :)