# How to redirect to a new window after click on option of select about html?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, select

For example:

```
<select>
  <option value=''>Select...</option>
  <option value='http://www.google.com'>Google</option>
  <option value='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

I want to redirect the selected site in a new window, such as link's attributes:

```
target='_blank'
```

I have found:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
```

But it can only redirect to the site on current page.

Comment: s-cho-m Question already existed on the stack overflow

   [Your Answer][1]

 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562095/redirect-on-select-option-in-select-box

Comment: Yes, I found that question, but not helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well :

```
<select onchange="(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value?  window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank'):'')">
<option value='' >Select...</option>
<option value='http://www.google.com'>Google</option>
<option value='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo</option>
```

Comment: Thank you. But use this method I can see a Pop-up blocked alert by Chrome browser.

Comment: r u using jsfiddle to test ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yqn4hzan/),

updated the markup as

```
<select onchange="openInNewTab(this);">
  <option value=''>Select...</option>
  <option value='http://www.google.com'>Google</option>
  <option value='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function openInNewTab(obj)
{
    //alert(obj.value);
    var win = window.open(obj.value, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. But use this method I can see a Pop-up blocked alert by Chrome browser.