# How can I have a link in my select options but not all should be a link

Tags: html

I have a dropdown list of users from my database, then at the last row I want to make a static option to create a new user and redirect the user to another page,

Tried to post the link in value, or enter in `<a>` tags or add an `href`, but with no success.

```
    <label for="cars">Assign to:</label>
        <select id="cars" name="assignTo" required>
            <option value=""></option>
                      <option value="Jey">Jey</option>
                    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
                      <option value="Moses">Moses</option>
                    <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
  <option value="" href="/add-user.php">Add new user</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but option doesn't have an href attribute. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: You can put link inside value of the option then in the select you can use javascript to do redirect, you just need to check if value contains the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562129/10634638

Comment: I am trying to have some regular options and one to a link, if I use JS all will be directed and the file does not exist as this is the name of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an onchange event check the value when it is changed, and use the `open` function to redirect:

```js
var cars = document.getElementById("cars")

cars.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (cars.value == "addUser") {
    open("/add-user.php", "_self")
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="cars">Assign to:</label>
<select id="cars" name="assignTo" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Jey">Jey</option>
  <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
  <option value="Moses">Moses</option>
  <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
  <option value="addUser">Add new user</option>
</select>
```

When it is changed, it checks the value for `addUser`, and if it is, it will redirect the user to the page.