# Redirect to route inside Select options in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using `Laravel` and inside a `blade` file i want to redirect to route each time an option is being selected. I tried the code below but it doesn’t redirect to the link when i select an option :

```html
<select name="zone" autocomplete="off" class="custom-select">
  <option data-placeholder="true">Zone</option>
    @foreach ($zones as $key => $zone)
      <option value="{{ $key }}">
        <a href="{{ route(Route::current()->getName(), ['zone' => $zone]) }}">
          {{ $zone }}
        </a>
      </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect on select option in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562095/redirect-on-select-option-in-select-box)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use links in select input. Instead use javascript like this:

```
<select onchange="window.location.assign('{{ url()->current().'?zone=' }}'+this.value)" name="zone" autocomplete="off" class="custom-select">
  <option data-placeholder="true">Zone</option>
    @foreach ($zones as $key => $zone)
      <option value="{{ $key }}">
        {{ $zone }}
      </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by setting the option value as the route you want to redirect to, and put the onchange event like: `onchange="window.location.href=this.value;"`

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select name="zone" autocomplete="off" class="custom-select" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
         <option data-placeholder="true">Zone</option>
            @foreach ($zones as $key => $zone)
              <option value="{{ route(Route::current()->getName(), ['zone' => $zone]) }}"></option>
            @endforeach
      </select> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of javascript or jquery here.

```
$('.custom-select').change(function(){
   //write you code here 
})
```