# How to redirect page when select option HTML, Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, onchange

I need to redirect page when one of the option is selected.

```html
<select required name="subject"  id="konu" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>Choose Subject</option>
  <option value="Ask a question">Ask a question</option>
  <option value="Leave a comment">Leave a comment</option>
  <option value="Where to buy">Where to buy</option>
  <option value="Product Complaint">Product Complaint</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option {{ request('subject') == 'Request SDS' ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="Request SDS">Request SDS</option>
  <option value="Distributor">Request Distributorship</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I once needed this too and found that your question has already been answered.

If you're fine with using inline JavaScript, check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562129/10440010

If you prefer staying off of inline, check out this answer under the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562201/10440010

I hope this helps!

**Update:**

An easy way of making it work for specific options, is to make the onChange event check whether the value of the clicked option equal to something. In the snippet below, I make it work for all links starting with `HTTPS`.

HTML:

```html
<select id="redirectSelect">
    <option value="NoLink" disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="NoLinkEither">Option 1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.com/">External Link</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function redirect(goto) {
  var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to go elswhere?");
  if (conf && goto != '') {
    window.location = goto;
  }
}

var selectEl = document.getElementById('redirectSelect');

selectEl.onchange = function() {
  if (this.value.startsWith('https')) {
    var goto = this.value;
    redirect(goto);
  }
};
```

Hopefully this helps you enough to solve your problem. If not, leave a comment and I am glad to help!

Comment: This code affect all options. Can I refer it for one specific option?

Comment: I have added a few snippets to allow the behavior you asked for @FaridAlishov

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome codder, but I have something wrong, I posted my code previously used. It is not working also

Answer (score 0):

I have a code previously woked.Here is select

```
<select required name="subject" id="konu" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" disabled>Choose Subject</option>
                                <option value="Ask a question">Ask a question</option>
                                <option value="Leave a comment">Leave a comment</option>
                                <option value="Where to buy">Where to buy</option>
                                <option value="Product Complaint">Product Complaint</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                <option {{ request('subject') == 'Request SDS' ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="Request SDS">Request SDS</option>
                                <option value="Distributor">Request Distributorship</option>
                            </select>
```

Here it is script.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#konu").change(function(){
                var value = $("#konu").val();
                if(value=="distributor"){
                    window.location = 'be-our-distributor';
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: But now it is not working I have a something wrong

Comment: add this js code on question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ~window.location = 'be-our-distributor'; ~  change this to orignal URL as it doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

For the second answer, the value used in your HTML differs from the value you're checking against in the JavaScript code.

In your HTML, it's `Distributor` and in your JavaScript code it's `distributor`. Mind the capital D.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on your condition. Your value is Distributor and u using distributor. Js is case sensetive so you not getting any redirection. the code should look like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#konu").change(function(){
            var value = $("#konu").val();
            if(value=="Distributor"){
                window.location = 'be-our-distributor';
            }
        })
    });
```